# Let $A=(5, -2)$ and $B=(8, y)$. If $AB= \sqrt{58}$ and $y \geq 5$, then $y =$

Tags: geometry

Can anyone help me on this? My answer is C, but the answer sheet says E. I can't find where I was wrong. Thank you very much!

Problem: Let $A=(5, -2)$ and $B=(8, y)$. If $AB= \sqrt{58}$ and $y \geq 5$, then $y =$

A. $10$, B. $6$, C. $5$, D. $-9$, E. None of these

Comment: What is $AB$? By the way, do you know that one can accept answers ? If $AB$ is the dot product, then $5\cdot 8-2y=\sqrt{58}$, hence $y$ is not an integer, hence $E$.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: If $AB$ represents the distance between points $A$ and $B$, your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

$AB=\sqrt{9+(y+2)^2}=\sqrt{58}\implies (y+2)^2=49\implies y+2=(\pm7)\implies y=5$or $y=-9$

After applying the given codition the answer comes out to be$5$. If your key shows other answer, wait till the key is reviewed.

Comment: To obtain $\pm$, type \pm in math mode.  Also, you wrote $y + 2 = 5$ or $y + 2 = -9$, which is not what you meant.  You are missing the step $y + 2 = \pm 7 \implies y = 5$ or $y = -9$.

Comment: thanks sir.Actually I have problem with mathjax and typing.It is first time here when i came to know about mathjax.