# find ratio of triangle perimeters

Tags: geometry

Can anyone help me on this problem? It is a multiple choice problem. My answer is E, but the answer sheet is B. The problem seems pretty easy, but I can't find out what I did wrong.

In the figure at the right, ∠ABD=30°, ∠BAE=60°, and the perpendiculars are as indicated. The ratio of the perimeter of ∆ABC to the perimeter of ∆BDE is A) 1:2, B) √ 3:3, C) 1:3, D) 1:6, E) None of these.

[image]

Comment: The answer should be $AC:BD$ and I'm getting that that is $1/2:3/4$ = $2:3$ or none of the above.  Is that what you got?  If BC = 1 then AC = 1/2 and AB = $\sqrt{3}/2$ and $BD = $\sqrt{3}/2*AB= 3/4$.  So...  I've triple checked...

Comment: Are you sure the triangle in question is BDE and not ABE.  The proportion of ABE (as snoram pointed out) has answer B.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to see these triangles are all 30-60-90 triangles.  (complementary angles adding to right angles, opposite angles of right triangles adding to 90, etc.)  The proportions if the sides of a 30-60-90 are hypotenuse =h, and sides 1/2 h and $\sqrt{3}/2$h.

Let BC = 1 unit; AC = 1/2 unit and AB = $\sqrt{3}/2$ units.

Then ADB is also a 30-60-90 triangle with AB = hypotenuse = $\sqrt{3}/2$ units.  So BD = $\sqrt{3}/2* $h = $\sqrt{3}/2*\sqrt{3}/2 = 3/4$.

BD in triangle BDE cooresponds with AC in triangle ABC.  So each side is of BDE is proportional by a factor of $BD/AC = (3/4)/(1/2) = 3/2$ so the answer is $2:3$ and ... none of the above.

So... the answer is wrong, I guess.

Unless I'm making a mistake, which does happen.

Answer (score 0):

Since $m\angle ABD = 30^\circ$ and $\overline{AB} \perp \overline{BE}$, $m\angle DBE = 60^\circ$.

Since $m\angle DBE = 60^\circ$ and $\overline{BC} \perp \overline{AE}$, $m\angle AEB = 30^\circ$.

Since $m\angle ABD = 30^\circ$ and $\overline{AB} \perp \overline{AC}$, $m\angle ACB = 30^\circ$.

Thus, $\triangle ABC \sim \triangle EDB$ by the Angle-Angle Similarity Theorem.

Since the ratio of the side lengths in a $30^\circ - 60^\circ - 90^\circ$ triangle is $1 : \sqrt{3} : 2$, in $\triangle ABD$, if $AD = x$, then $BD = x\sqrt{3}$ and $AB = 2x$.

For the same reason in $\triangle BDE$, since $BD = x\sqrt{3}$, then $DE = 3x$ and $BE = 2x\sqrt{3}$.

The ratio of the perimeters of similar triangles is the ratio of the side lengths of corresponding sides.  Hence, the ratio of the perimeter of $\triangle ABC$ to the perimeter of $\triangle EDB$ is 
$$\frac{AB}{DE} = \frac{2x}{3x} = \frac{2}{3}$$

Comment: i.e. None of these?  I'm wondering if the OP wrote the question wrong or the writers of the problem made a typo.  B is the correct answer if we are comparing ABC to ABE.  But for BDE it's clearly 2: 3.

Comment: @fleablood  This is the second question the OP posed today in which the OP got a different answer from the key.  In both cases, the OP was right.  Here is the [other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1726090/let-a-5-2-and-b-8-y-if-ab-sqrt58-and-y-geq-5-then-y).

Comment: Who's creating the keys?  The mistake on this question is understandable as temporary confusion, but the other one is inexcusable.